# How is this code is reachable in this recursion function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement, recursion

I'm doing a sudoku solver and found this code online, which used a snimilar method to what I was doing, but I don't understand how `grid[y][x] = 0` is able to be reached in this code since it calls `solve(grid)`in the line before.

I've noticed I get the same output if I put a `else` statement before it (and as well if it has on less indent)

```
def solve(grid):
    for y in range(9):
        for x in range(9):
            if grid[y][x] == 0:
                for n in range(1, 10):
                    if possible(y, x, n, grid):
                        grid[y][x] = n
                        solve(grid)
                        grid[y][x] = 0  # How is the program able to reach this code if it calls solve(grid) before it's able to be reached? 

                return

    print(np.matrix(grid))
```

Comment: Obvious answer: this line executed after return from `solve()`.

Comment: Why do you think it should not be reached? A recursive call is no different from a regular call - once the call returns, the outer function resumes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a recursive solution. Recursive means that the solve function calls itself. It continues it's code when the program returns from calling.

```
grid[y][x] = n     # current solve changes grid
solve(grid)        # call recursively solve
                   # the function solve has now returned
                   # and can have changed grid 
grid[y][x] = 0     # now the current solve continues
```

This works because a list like grid is a mutable object which means that the called function can change grid and the caller continues with the changed grid.

There is one condition: there must be some condition inside solve so that after calling itself multiple times the last called solve returns.

Compare it with the well known Fibonacci function:

```
def F(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return F(n - 1) + F(n - 2)

print(F(6))
```

It stops calling itself when n==0 or n==1. Before that it keeps calling itself with n-1 and n-2.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what bugs you - it's just a plain ordinary function call. Obviously a function can call another function, else we couldn't do much.

NB : what the name `solve` points to is resolved at runtime - the only thing happening at compile time here is that the generated byte-code knows it has to resolve the name `solve` and apply the call op to whatever this name resolves to.

Comment: Yeah I know. There is nothing wrong with the code, I just wanted to understand the principal behind it

Comment: @IsaacK0 I'mp not saying there's anything wrong, just that there aren't any reason to wonder how it can work nor why a recursive call would prevent the next line from being executed.